# How to prevent NuGet from spamming build output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

During project build NuGet writes to the output a similar message (see below) for each project in solution. This message is way too long and basically useless. It only happens after someone enables NuGet package restore for solution (.nuget folder in solution). I don't want to disable package restore, I just want to disable this message.

```
14>  Restoring NuGet packages...
14>  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
14>  Feeds used:
14>    C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
14>    C:\Users\Peter\.nuget\packages\
14>    Z:\Install\NugetPackages
14>    https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
14>  
14>  All packages listed in C:\BestProject14\packages.config are already installed.
```

Comment: Why do you care whether your build output looks nice? :O

Comment: Actually you are using the OLD package restore fuction (MSBuild based). You should migrate your projects to the NEW method. Read https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore and especially the section on Automatic restore and migrating to new format.

Comment: @MariuszJamro because some errors in error list need context that I can find easily in Output window (link errors, c++ template errors etc).

Comment: @Kiliman I do prefer the new method but one colleague said it doesn't work for him (I think it is his fault, but I didn't want to argue) so he enabled package restore for solution. I would migrate it to automatic restore but it is quite tedious work. I will test script mentioned in your link: https://github.com/owen2/AutomaticPackageRestoreMigrationScript